# UNIX: how to merge 2 text files?

Tags: unix, text-manipulation

Is there a way to merge 2 text files into one (by appending the content of the second right after the first one) in Unix ?

Comment: Not really a merge, you just append one file after another.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming `bash` as shell or bash script...

---

Append `file2` to `file1` (keeping file2 in original state):

`cat file2 >> file1`

---

Or this (keeping both original files around):

`cat file1 file2 > new_merged_file`